# awk: grouping blocks of text of the last word is common in both text files

Tags: awk, sed

I have two file text formatted in this way

**1.txt**

```
11
aa
bb

22
dd
ee
```

**2.txt**

```
qq;ww;aa;
qq;zz;bb;

qq;yy;dd;
qq;hh;ee;
```

[image]

I try to obtain a 3.txt file formatted in this way

```
11
aa
bb
qq;ww;aa;
qq;zz;bb;

22
dd
ee
qq;yy;dd;
qq;hh;ee;
```

I use this `.awk` script

```
awk -f script.awk 2.txt 1.txt

BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
{sub(/;$/,"")}
NR==FNR{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;++i)
        for (j=1;j<=NF;++j)
            if (j!=i&&!b[$i,$j]++)
                a[$i,++c[$i]]=$j
    next
}
{
    delete b
    for (i=1;i<=NF;++i)
        ++b[$i]
    for (i=1;i<=NF;++i)
        for (j=1;j<=c[$i];++j)
            if (!b[a[$i,j]]++)
                $(NF+1)=a[$i,j]
    print
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples/attempts only, please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

***1st solution:*** This will match each set(from 1.txt and 2.txt)'s last element if they are equal then it will print the sets from both the files eg: (bb from 1.txt is matched with bb; from 2.txt in 1st set(line in case of RS is on paragraph mode) of both the file)

```
awk -v RS=""  '
FNR==NR{
  arr[FNR]=$0
  next
}
{
  num1=split(arr[FNR],tempArr1,"\n")
  num2=split($0,tempArr2,"\n")
  num3=split(tempArr2[num2],tempArr3,";")
  if(tempArr3[num3-1]==tempArr1[num1]){
    print arr[FNR] ORS $0
  }
}
' 1.txt 2.txt
```

---

***2nd solution:*** This considers that values of last lines of each set(from file1 and file2) could be find in anywhere(irrespective of place, like 1st solution specifically compares last position of is equal or not for both file's same set(lines)).

```
awk -v RS="" '
FNR==NR{
  arr[FNR]=$0
  next
}
{
  num1=split(arr[FNR],tempArr1,"\n")
  num2=split($0,tempArr2,"\n")
  if(index(tempArr2[num2],tempArr1[num1])){
    print arr[FNR] ORS $0
  }
}
' 1.txt 2.txt
```

---

---

***NOTE:*** To run program(taking example of 1st code given above here) in `.awk` script format, create `script.awk` script file and make sure it has proper permissions to run:

```
cat script.awk
FNR==NR{
  arr[FNR]=$0
  next
}
{
  num1=split(arr[FNR],tempArr1,"\n")
  num2=split($0,tempArr2,"\n")
  num3=split(tempArr2[num2],tempArr3,";")
  if(tempArr3[num3-1]==tempArr1[num1]){
    print arr[FNR] ORS $0
  }
}
```

***IN both solutions*** Run above `scipt.awk` as follows:

```
awk -v RS="" -f script.awk 1.txt 2.txt
```

Comment: ok, I tested but it doesn't work. Please look [THIS](https://i.imgur.com/eRzc6jh.gif) to understand

Comment: @AlexDoc, sorry I couldn't understand there. Could you please explain me here what's not working? With your shown samples it works fine for me.

Comment: @AlexDoc. Please try to run only awk script on terminal first and see what output it's giving

Comment: it return me this error. I use cygwin: fitst I type this command `awk -f script.awk` and in terminal then I get
`awk: script.awk:1: awk -v RS=""  '
awk: script.awk:1:          ^ syntax error
awk: script.awk:1: awk -v RS=""  '
awk: script.awk:1:               ^ carattere ''' non valido in un'espressione`

Comment: it say me character not valid `'` - I have not this error if I type `sh script.awk` but if you look my link on comments you can see that text is not formatted well

Comment: @AlexDoc, you can't run `awk` script like what you are doing now. Please run first my whole code(copy paste it on your terminal) and you will see output then, once you confirm this then I could add how to run it in .awk file. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @AlexDoc, I have updated my answer on how to run code as .awk program. You could test my code with running on terminal(as suggested in my previous comment) AND then try my NOTE: suggestion too. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: ok, I copy and paste your code on terminal but output return a wrong formatted text, I can show you with a picture https://imgur.com/uZ7qxDo.png - 2. Running as program (I copy and paste to make script.awk without `cat script.awk`) it return me same wrong formatting. I use cygwin under windows

Comment: @AlexDoc, this is a working command in Linux system. I don't have cygwin with me so can't say about it.

Comment: yes, you are right. I test on linux from a vps and it works. You can see [here](https://imgur.com/EVwXK7S.png) - Thank you very much

Comment: @AlexDoc, Your welcome, happy to help, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by manipulating `RS` and `FS` appropriately, e.g.:

*combine.awk*

```
# Remember content from 1.txt with $NF as the key
FNR == NR {
  h[$NF] = $0
  next
}

# If the last element in 2.txt is in the hash
$(NF-1) in h {
  print h[$(NF-1)]
  print $0 "\n"
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f combine.awk RS= FS='\n' 1.txt FS='[;\n]' 2.txt
```

Output:

```
11
aa
bb
qq;ww;aa;
qq;zz;bb;

22
dd
ee
qq;yy;dd;
qq;hh;ee;
```